# ASP.NET and C# upload a mp3 file to a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, upload

I want to upload a music file to a database, but i don't know how. I need to upload the file to server and then upload it to the database? Or I can do everything at the same time? And how i can do it?

Comment: You want to embed the MP3 inside the Database or store the path as a string inside the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no shortage of tutorials on how to do this.  [Here's a decent one](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304133428/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120606-1.aspx).  Basically, what you're asking is how to store a file as a binary stream in a database field.

However, @Saif al Harthi makes a good point in his comment.  It's generally considered bad practice to store a binary file in a relational database.  Are you sure this is what you want to do?  Your server already has a fairly efficient means of storing/retrieving files... the file system.  Unless there's a compelling reason to store the file in the database, it's usually better practice to store it on the file system and just write a database record that references the file (path, maybe type, other application-specific data about it, etc.).  The file's name can be changed to, say, the primary identifier for the database table in order to easily reference between them.

It's a little more work, but it's a little better for the server and makes use of the right tools for the right jobs.  That is, of course, unless you have a compelling reason for keeping a binary file in a relational database.  If there's a reason, please share it.